# Scroll Lock key on for keyboard lights but off for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard

My keyboard uses the Scroll Lock key to turn the lights for the keys and key background on and off. Excel uses the same key to control movement when using the arrow keys. How can I "tell" Excel the Scroll Lock key is always off even when it is on? I have to believe there is a registry entry I could make do this. Remapping the keyboard doesn't work. I remap the Scroll Lock key and the keyboard reads that key as well. Any ideas please.

Comment: What brand and model is the keyboard? Perhaps we'll find a solution through the manufacturer documentations.

Comment: The keyboard is a Cooler Master CMSTORM Devastortor. I have been in touch with them and the tech seems to be knowldeable about this problem and apologizes that they are aware of this and have no fix. Maybe they will address this in the next model release.I've tried Key Remapper and blocked the key only in Excel Only as they allow but still can't get past it. I don't know but it seems to me that there could be a way (in the regestry?) to "tell" Excel that the key is "off" and not to detect a change. It's probably "burried deep in the low level OS routine to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue with a cmstorm and made a research a whole day. Please check the following links:

https://bgreodica.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/how-to-disable-the-cm-storm-devastator-onoff-switch-via-scroll-key/

https://youtu.be/W4n4oKf1ATo

In both you will find that in order to fix it you need to make hardware modifications (this will void your warranty).

You will solder a cable to feed power into the backlight instead letting it wait for power coming from the scrlk button's led light when active.

I tried to find a software solution but it seems there isn't any for windows. For Linux it may be possible to achieve the control through software.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I`ve done the modification following his tutorial, problem fixed, about 30 min. You need to know how to solder electronic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4n4oKf1ATo&feature=youtu.be Drew Smith

Comment: I am glad the link worked for you.